# Create Extension for Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am playing around with the Magento 2 beta and in doing so attempting to create a custom extension. I have had a good read through the docs and think I understand most of the process, however I am having trouble getting Magento to register my extension.

I have created a new directory in app/code/My/Extension to contain the extension within this I have created an etc/module.xml file which if my understanding is correct should cause magento to register the extension. My module.xml code contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="My_Extension" schema_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Eav"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

I can tell Magento is getting as far as reading this file as if I break the xml it causes an error loading the config in developer mode. However if I go to Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output in admin I cannot see my new extension which is what I was expecting. Obviously there is a lot more to do after this step but I just want to get past this first hurdle. Am I missing something? Is there anything else that needs to be done to actually register the extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fells like a duplicate of a recent question. Just recently a config.php file was introduced in app/etc. I have an internal question for the developer on the "right" way to add a new module, but until then please make sure you add your new module to config.php by hand. This file controls which modules get loaded and in what order.

(I think you can rerun the setup script as well, but not sure how to preserve the DB connection info - which is why I am waiting for the "official" way to do it.)

Comment: Ok thanks Alan, I will give that a shot. Sorry I didn't see the previous question.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to create module in Magento 2:
 - Create Directories

- Configuration of Module
- Registration of Module
- Front End Router File
- Create Controller
- Create Block
- Frontend layout File
- Frontend Template File
- Module Activation